# Regex to check for Capital letters OR small letters if @ is used at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

So I have this regex that checks for string and place them on their proper div class if it matches it. The regex I use for characters are below:

```
character: /^([A-Z*_]+[0-9A-Z# (,._\-')]*)/
```

and it checks the string if it's all caps, if yes then place it on `<div class="character"></div>` tag.

I'd like to place a conditional inside the regex if possible where, if the string is 'McMAHON' or 'McDONALD', it can be placed inside the character tag provided that they use an @ sign at the beginning. e.g. '@McDONALD'

Right now, what I have is this that checks for this structure.

```
character: /^([@A-Z*_]+[0-9A-Za-z# (,._\-')]*)/,
```

Which defeats the purpose of regex matching for characters as they can type 'John' even without the '@'.

The string sample expected to be placed on this tag are the following:

```
    'JOHN'
    'EXTRA #1'
    'M.C. HAMMER'
    '@M.C. McDONALD' - I can remove the @ before pushing the string
    'ANDROID #D-C_1'
    '@McDONALD' - I can remove the @ before pushing the string
```

Comment: I updated it with few character string samples

Comment: yes that's right.. so I have to do tokens.push({ type: 'character', text: match[1].replace(/\@/g, '').trim() }); if @ is at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that you list your `-`, in your character classes, at the beginning or end of the list so that you don't create a "range" of characters.

Also you can make your pattern more brief if you use `\w` to represent `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

`^(@+[\w# (,.\'-]*|[A-Z]+[0-9A-Z# (,._\'-]*)$`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0PW2M/3)

Answer (score 0):

this looks great. Just had to complete it and it's all good.. https://regex101.com/r/o0PW2M/2 ..Thanks a lot @Nosyara for the insight..You've removed your answer though..